# Why doesn't this part of an if statement work?

Tags: c

This is part of nested if statement, and only this part does not work. When it is part of the nested if statement, the output shows the execution of the part that works. When it is separated from the nested if statement, it does not show output at all.

*Wanted input and output*
Input: S 14 16
Output: Money: 127.99 
        Time: 16:00

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char type;
    float money = 127.99;
    int hour, min;
    int hour_min;


    printf("Type, time of departure: \n ");
    scanf(" %c %d%d", &type, &hour, &min);
    hour_min = hour*60 + min;


  if ((type == 'S') && (hour >= '14'))
    {

        float money = 127.99;
        hour_min += 104;
        hour = hour_min/60;
        min = hour_min%60;
        printf("Money: %.2f\Time: %d:%.2d", money, hour, min);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does your compiler say..... it should be screaming at you, very obvious mistake :)

Comment: Note the difference between `'14'` vs `14`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you, this part works fine now. But another problem occurred. 

*Wanted* Input: S 9 44
                Output: 70.71 11:28

Instead of 70.71, it shows 108.79

`else if ((type =='S') && (hour < 10))
    {
        ticket = (127.99*0.85)*0.65;
        hour_min += 104;
        hour = hour_min/60;
        min = hour_min%60;
        printf("Money: %.2f\nTime: %d:%.2d", money, hour, min);

    }`

Comment: You're assigning to `ticket` but printing `money`

Comment: @Barmar It's typo, sorry. Instead of ticket should be money. It does not work anyway.

Comment: That's what you would get from `money = 127.99 * 0.85;`, without multiplying by `0.65;`. Check your code to make sure all the multiplications are really happening.

Comment: @Barmar so this one actually works fine on its own, but not when its part of the if statements.

Comment: Post the full code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201051/discussion-between-newya-and-barmar).